# Reduced homology of a point is trivial from axioms

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, axioms

In the section *Axioms for homology* from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* (page 161) he says:

> Note that $\tilde{h}_n(x_0) = 0$ for all $n$,
>   as can be seen by looking at the long exact sequence of reduced homology groups of
>   the pair $(x_0,x_0)$.

I guess that he means the exact sequence of the second axiom, which gives the boundary map $\partial :\tilde{h}_n(X/A)\to\tilde{h}_{n-1}(A)$.

From this it is clear that $\tilde{h}_n(x_0)=\tilde{h}_{n-1}(x_0)$ for all $n$. But Hatcher is not assuming the dimension axiom, so I cannot say that $\tilde{h}_n(x_0)=0$ for $n\neq 0$, so how could I conclude that $\tilde{h}_n(x_0) = 0$ for all $n$?

I've thought that this could be shown using the first axiom if I could show that constant maps induce trivial maps in homology, but I don't see how to deduce this fact from the axioms because the proof I know for singular, cellular or simplicial homology uses that the homology of a point is trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure how you concluded that $\tilde{h}_n(x_0)=\tilde{h}_{n-1}(x_0)$.  There is a boundary map between them, but why would that map be an isomorphism?  (In fact it is since both groups are trivial, but I don't know what logic you're using.)

Comment: @EricWofsey in this case, $X=A=x_0$, so $X/A=A$, and the boundary map is an isomorphism.

Comment: But...why is it an isomorphism?

Comment: @EricWofsey I was going to write my argument but I found the mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have an exact sequence $$\tilde{h}_n(A)\stackrel{i_*}\to\tilde{h}_n(X)\stackrel{q_*}\to\tilde{h}_n(X/A)$$ where the first map is induced by the inclusion $i:A\to X$ and the second map is induced by the quotient map $q:X\to X/A$.  But if $X$ and $A$ are both just a point, then $i$ and $q$ are both homeomorphisms, so $i_*$ and $q_*$ are both isomorphisms.  But the image of $i_*$ is the kernel of $q_*$, so this implies $q_*=0$, and so $\tilde{h}_n(X)=0$ since $q_*$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hatcher's definition of a reduced homology theory is limited to CW-pairs. A more general definition for **general pairs** is this: Omit axiom 3 and replace the long exact sequence in axiom 2 by
$$\dots \stackrel{\partial}{\rightarrow} \tilde{h}_n(A) \stackrel{i_*}{\rightarrow} \tilde{h}_n(X) \stackrel{j_*}{\rightarrow} \tilde{h}_n(X \cup CA) \stackrel{\partial}{\rightarrow} \dots$$
Here, $CA$ is the unreduced cone on $A$ and $X \cup CA$ is the adjunction space in which the equivalence class $[a,0] \in CA$ in the base of $CA$ is identified with $a \in A \subset X$. For CW-pairs this is equivalent to Hatcher's long exact sequence. In fact, if $(X,A)$ is CW-pair, then $(X \cup CA, CA)$ is also a CW-pair, in a particular $CA \hookrightarrow X \cup CA$ is cofibration. Since $CA$ is contractible, the quotient map $p : X \cup CA \to (X \cup CA)/CA = X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Now consider $(X,A) = (x_0,x_0)$. Then $X \cup CA$ is homeomorphic to the unit interval whence $j_*$ is an isomorphism. Since $i_*$ trivially is an isomorphism, we conclude that
$\tilde{h}_n(x_0) = 0$ for all $n$.

Added:

Hatcher's approach to axiomatic homology is not standard. In fact, he gives an axiomatic definition of a *reduced single space homology theory for unbased spaces*. This means that no relative groups $\tilde{h}_n(X,A)$ are used.

Such theories for *unbased spaces* are considered only rarely in the literature (but is a common to work with reduced single space homology theory for *based spaces*, although their definition is different from Hatchers's).

If you consider singular homology defined for all pairs of toplogical spaces, then it is well known that *reduced singular homology groups* can be defined via the augmented chain complex.

A more general approach is this: If we have a generalized homology theory $(H_n,\partial)$ satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms with the possible exception of the dimension axiom, we can define *reduced groups* by
$$\tilde{H}_n(X) = \ker (p_* : H_n(X) \to H_n(*)) \subset H_n(X)$$
where $p : X \to *$ is the unique map to a one-point space $*$.
It is then an easy exercise to show that we get a long exact sequence
$$\dots \stackrel{\partial}{\rightarrow} \tilde{H}_n(A) \stackrel{i_*}{\rightarrow} \tilde{H}_n(X) \stackrel{j_*}{\rightarrow} H_n(X,A) \stackrel{\partial}{\rightarrow} \tilde{H}_{n-1} (A)\stackrel{i_*}{\rightarrow}  \dots $$
The excision axiom shows that $H_n(X,A) \approx H_n(X \cup CA,CA)$ and the latter is easily seen to be isomorphic to $\tilde{H}_n(X \cup CA)$. This yields the exact sequence from above. Note that it does *not agree* with Hatcher's exact sequence, except if restrict to CW-pairs.

In the case of reduced singular homology the definition via the augmented chain complex and our general definition agree and we have $\tilde{H}_n(X) = H_n(X)$ for $n > 0$. But reduced singular homology does not satisfy Hatchers's axiom 2 (long exact sequence with quotients $X/A$). Consider for example the pair $(T,J)$ where $T = \{ x,\sin(1/x)) \mid x \in (0,1] \} \cup  \{ 0 \} \times [-1,1]$ is the closed topologist's sine curve and $J = \{ 0 \} \times [-1,1]$. The space $T$ has two path components which are contractible and $T/J$ is homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$, i.e. contractible. Hence $\tilde{H}_0(J) = 0, \tilde{H}_0(T) = \mathbb {Z}, \tilde{H}_0(T/J) = 0$ which shows that $\tilde{H}_0(J) \stackrel{i_*}{\rightarrow} \tilde{H}_0(T) \stackrel{p_*}{\rightarrow} H_0(T/J)$ cannot be exact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Javi I added some material.